# Increase numbers by one in a visual block

Tags: regular-expression, functions, filetype-xml

I edit DocBook XML files. In my plugin, i want to implement a function that would increase or decrease the section numbers recursively, assuming that cursor is at the toplevel section. For example, when my cursor is at the top `<sect2` element, it means to turn

```
<sect2>
 <sect3>
  <sect4>
  <para>some text</para>
  </sect4>
 </sect3>
</sect2>
```

into

```
<sect1>
 <sect2>
  <sect3>
  <para>some text</para>
  </sect3>
 </sect2>
</sect1>
```

i have this code in my script, but it does not work:

```
execute 'normal vat' # select the text up to the closing tag
execute 'normal :s/sect\(\d\?\)>/\="sect" . (submatch(1) - 1). ">"/g'
```

but it does not work. any idea?

Comment: `:s` is an ex command,  it can be executed directly.

Comment: @dedowsdi so is `normal`; none of the commands here require `execute` at all. Plus we should really use `normal!` unless we know what we are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visually select your lines and press `CTRL-x` to decrease them.

From `:help v_CTRL-x`:

> ```
> v_CTRL-X                                             {Visual}CTRL-X
>                     Subtract [count] from the number or alphabetic                                                                                        
>                     character in the highlighted text.  {not in Vi}
> ```

See also `:help CTRL-x`. And you can use `CTRL-a` to increment.

In your vimscript, it will that (tested):

```
" select the text up to the closing tag
execute 'normal vat'
" Here the double quotes are important for the <C-X> to be executed
execute "normal \<C-X>"
```

EDIT: To decrement only the "sect", you can use this function, however you need to do the selection before calling it (I haven't found a way to make a selection and use `'<` and `'>` both from within the function, if anyone has a suggestion):

```
function! DecSect()
    silent! substitute/sect\(\d\)>/\="sect".(submatch(1) - 1).">"/g
endfunc
command -range -nargs=0 DecSect <line1>,<line2>call DecSect()
```

On the other hand, externalizing the visual selection gives you more flexibility to use it (you can use it on a tag, paragraph, document, line...), cf below.

To use it, first visual select the section you want to apply it on:

```
vat
vap
%
....
```

Then call it:

```
:'<,'>DecSect
```

Or just call it directly to execute it on the current line:

```
:DecSect
```

Comment: But that increments all the numbers, right? I only need to increase/decrease <sectX> parts.

Comment: Indeed. If you have potentially other numbers, let me see what else can be done. Also, your lines containing the `sectX`, do they contain other numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately, they might, i cannot control users' formatting. My regexp works perfectly when run manually from the buffer cmdline, but refuses to run from the script. I suspect that problem is in the `substitute` command, it probably does not respect the previous `vat` and has no range to run on maybe?

Comment: Edited with a function you can put in your `.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
normal! vat
substitute/sect\(\d\)>/\="sect".(submatch(1) - 1).">"/
```

I’ve removed the `execute`s, because the commands provides are valid vimscript commands and don’t need it.

I used `normal!` to avoid mappings interfering.

Finally, I removed the `\?` option on the digits, since your example always has digits after the `sect`s.

There are other ways to accomplish the same idea. For example:

1. `qa` start a macro
2. `<C-X>` increment
3. `q` stop macro
4. (Optional) if step (2) caused changes in the buffer, undo them with `u`
5. `g/sect\d/normal! @a` Run the macro on section lines. `<C-X>` by default will jump to the first number on a line for decrements.

From a script, steps (1)-(4) can be replaced by

1. `let @a="\<C-X>"`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now the range seems to be the problem, and prepending '<,'> causes an error message. I simply need to find out the line number of the matching XML tag, maybe even without the `vat`,  that would solve everything.

Comment: @TomášBažant can you try the script version of the macro? See my edits.